# How do I display the unicode syntax (\uXXXX) from a string?

Tags: python, unicode

I tried methods like encode using "unicode-display", raw string, But it didn't work. I am writing a module for a chat bot in python which involves getting a character from the user and showing it in the "\uXXXX" format instead of it turning into the respective character.
Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import unicodedata as ud

class Unicode:
    """Encode Unicode characters!"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def unicode(self, *, character):
        """Encode a Unicode character."""
        try:
            data = ud.normalize('NFC', character)
        except ValueError:
            data = '<unknown>'
        await self.bot.say(data)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Unicode(bot))
```

Comment: Your indenting looks messed up

Comment: The indenting is proper

Comment: @RedstoneKiller18Gaming: it is now that I fixed it, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is the Unicode code point, get the `ord()` value and express that as a hex value:

```
'U+{:04X}'.format(ord(data[0]))
```

This will use at least 4 hex digits (uppercased) for a given character, more if the character is outside the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). I picked the widely accepted `U+hhhh` format rather than the Python / JSON / Javascript escape sequence format here.

Demo:

```
>>> data = '⛄'
>>> unicode_codepoint = 'U+{:04X}'.format(ord(data[0]))
>>> print(unicode_codepoint)
U+26C4
```

You could also encode the data to a JSON string or use the [`ascii()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) to create a string (with quotes) with `\u` escape sequences:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(data))
"\u26c4"
>>> print(ascii(data))
'\u26c4'
```

This has the downside that you now have to remove those quote characters again (use `str.strip()`).

The difference between the two approaches is that encoding to JSON produces [UTF-16 surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) for characters outside of the BMP, using `ascii()` you'll get `\Uhhhhhhhh` Python escape codes:

```
>>> data = ''
>>> print('U+{:04X}'.format(ord(data[0])))
U+1F596
>>> print(json.dumps(data))
"\ud83d\udd96"
>>> print(ascii(data))
'\U0001f596'
```

Comment: Hmm, thought you could also call `repr('⛄')`, but that just gives '⛄'.

Comment: @NickT: You are thinking of `repr()` in Python 2.. in Python 3 you need to use `ascii()` instead.

Comment: @RedstoneKiller18Gaming: "don't work" doesn't tell me anything, sorry.

Comment: @RedstoneKiller18Gaming: Ah, that means that something else in the bot pipeline interprets `\u` escape sequences.